# What makes this jsessionid shows up on this PHP-code result?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I want to do parsing on this site: [CiteSeerx Result](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/search?q=mean&t=doc&sort=rlv&start=0).

I tried this:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/search?q=mean&t=doc&sort=rlv&start=0';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page);

foreach ($html->find('div.result h3') as $title) {
   echo $title->plaintext . '<br/>';
}
echo '---<br>';

foreach ($html->find('div.result h3 a') as $link) {
   echo '\'http://citeseeerx.ist.psu.edu' . $link->href . '<br>';
}
echo '---<br>';

foreach ($html->find('div.pubinfo') as $info){
   echo $info->innertext. '<br>';
}
echo '---<br>';

foreach ($html->find('div.snippet') as $snippet){
   echo $snippet->innertext. '<br>';
}
?>
```

It works and gives me what I want, it's just that, this `jsessionid=...` shows up on every single line of the `$link` results.

What do I do to make it disappear? I googled for addressing this problem, but all I find is the way to solve it with Java, not PHP.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <a class="remove doc_details" href="/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=103B4C6E9ADA3C8B17DD64BD57238F9D?doi=10.1.1.160.3832">
```

because the href in the tag includes the jsession id part :)

Comment: But in the source file of that site it is written: <a class="remove doc_details" href="/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.160.3832"> there's no jsessionid in it. What have I missed?

Comment: I checked the source and I have copy pasted it :) jsessionid is there. Check again

EDIT:

OKay I checked again. Sometimes jsessionid is generated and sometimes it's not. The links are being generated dynamically. So its nothing to worry.

Comment: I intend to put all of them into array, (each has title, link, snippet and info). Then display them into my program. Will the 'jsessionid' block the way then? Thanks,,

Comment: It wont :) Its not an issue